# Apply single colors for all bars in seaborn countplot

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

Following codes give different colors for each category

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="darkgrid")
titanic = sns.load_dataset("titanic")
ax = sns.countplot(x="class", data=titanic)
```

how to make all of them have the same color?
[image]

Comment: like sns.countplot(x="class",data=titanic,color="k")

Comment: @Sheldore Thanks, in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62103220/extra-plot-when-drawing-catplot/62109247#62109247, you posted `plt.close(2)`, can you repost again? I wish to accept that (I saw you deleted the answer, and not sure who gives the downvote).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.countplot.html):

> seaborn.countplot(x=None, y=None, hue=None, data=None, order=None,
>   hue_order=None, orient=None, color=None, palette=None,
>   saturation=0.75, dodge=True, ax=None, **kwargs)

Function takes color argument, change it to change color.