# Extra Plot when drawing Catplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Using the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline
df1 = pd.DataFrame( {'category': {0: 'Cat', 1: 'Cat', 2: 'Cat', 3: 'Cat', 4: 'Dog', 5: 'Dog', 6: 'Dog', 7: 'Dog', 8: 'Dog', 9: 'Dog', 10: 'Dog', 11: 'Dog', 12: 'Dog', 13: 'Dog', 14: 'Dog', 15: 'Dog', 16: 'Dog', 17: 'Dog', 18: 'Dog', 19: 'Dog'}, 'shape': {0: 'Small', 1: 'Small', 2: 'Small', 3: 'Small', 4: 'Small', 5: 'Small', 6: 'Small', 7: 'Medium', 8: 'Medium', 9: 'Large', 10: 'Small', 11: 'Small', 12: 'Small', 13: 'Small', 14: 'Small', 15: 'Small', 16: 'Small', 17: 'Small', 18: 'Small', 19: 'Small'}} )
plt.figure(figsize=(5,5),facecolor='#ffffff')
ax = plt.axes(facecolor='#ffffff')
plt.xticks(rotation=25)
sns.catplot(x='shape', hue='category', kind ='count', data = df1, height=5, aspect=1,ax=ax)
plt.xlabel('Diamond Shape')
plt.show()
```

I got the following plot

[image]

Why there is an extra blank plot below? How to not generate that?
(I need the `ax` to provide extra formatting for catplot)

Comment: `ax=plt.axes(facecolor='#ffffff')`This is unnecessary?.

Comment: @r-beginners I am using ax to format the plot, I just reduce it to the bare minimal

Comment: If you comment out `sns.catplot()`, you will get only a blank graph.

Comment: `sns.catplot()` creates its own figure and possibly subplots. You need to call `sns.countplot()` directly if you only want one subplot. `sns.countplot(x='shape', hue='category', data=df1, ax=ax)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following trick : Close the extra figure before `plt.show()`

```
plt.close(2)
plt.show()
```